# How I make log by day in Symfony

Tags: symfony, logging, symfony4, monolog

community. I need make logs files daily with Symfony4; or push a current date in a yml file. Specifically in monologo.yml.

```
 handlers:
    app:
        type: stream
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/system_compact_%kernel.environment%-***date***.log"
        channels: ["app"]
```

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use can use "rotating_file" log type:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  rotating_file
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/system_compact_%kernel.environment%.log"
```

Look at this documentation page: https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html#how-to-rotate-your-log-files

Comment: How I specific 1 day? Thank u

Comment: `This handler creates a new log file every day`

Comment: Thank u very much, it was vary easy. I was getting crazy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35799588/9712077
if somebody needs keep files by n days, add to handler days range

  max_files:  30